# PaperTrail and Rails Minitest every time tests run, ids for newly created versions are incremented

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, minitest, paper-trail-gem

I am working on a rails app.

I have PaperTrail installed and I was using Sqlite but I am trying to switch my app to use PostgreSQL. The transition has seemed to go smoothly but I noticed a test I had was failing. Here it is.

```
test 'expects audit log page' do
  with_versioning do
    # Arrange
    user = users(:existing_investor)
    user.update(first_name: 'Vanilla')

    # Act
    get spikes_audit_log_url
    p PaperTrail::Version.where(event: "update").last # Prints out a new paper trail version. There is always only 1 available

    # Assert
    assert_response :success
    assert_select 'h1', 'Audit Log'
    assert_select 'td', text: '1' # This fails it keeps incrementing, the text is supposed to be the paper trail version id
  end
end
```

So as you can see I am trying to go to a page where I have a table view of paper trail versions, specifically those where the event was an Update. I am expecting the `td` that fails to be `1` the ID of the paper trail version created. I have verified there is only 1 paper trail version in my test database at the time of the asserts. However the ID is incrementing whenever I run the tests. It seems like it knows the previous versions had existed and then been destroyed.

I hope I am making sense let me know if I need to clear anything up. I know how to get the test to pass, but I'm wondering if it is expected that the ID continuously increment? I would expect whenever the tests are run that the database would get wiped, the fixtures would be created and then whenever I create a new paper trail version that its `ID` would be `1` but that is not the case.

Am I missing something from changing my app to PostgreSQL? Or is this expected. thanks!

Comment: It's normal for a primary key to increment [sequentially](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createsequence.html). So, it's not a good idea to assert a specific id. If you must assert id == 1, you can try dropping/re-creating your test db before running your tests.

Comment: @JaredBeck Thanks! Yeah I updated the test so it wouldn't always assert the id == 1. I thought the database would always drop/recreate for tests. I think maybe I need to update something in a config somewhere to do that. I just thought it was strange that it seemed to do it when I was running Sqlite but when I switched to postgres it wasn't.